# how to access this in onclick function inside a function?

Tags: javascript

The following code is not working.Some one please help me in this problem
The name of unit is not alerted.

```
function unit(name,svgCircle)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.cir = svgCircle;
    this.cir.onclick = clicking;
}
function clicking(){
    alert(this.name);
}
```

Comment: `this.cir.onclick = clicking.bind(this)` else the calling context will be `this.cir`

Comment: Are you calling the `unit` function with suitable arguments before calling the `clicking` function? Because you should.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, are you using angular or any other javascript

```js
 function unit(name,svgCircle)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.cir = svgCircle;
            this.cir.onclick = clicking.bind(this);
        }
        function clicking(){
            alert(this.name);
        }
 
 unit("ml", "testSvg");
 clicking();
```

Comment: i am using simple javascript

Comment: @MaheerAli, this will work, you can check in console also.

Comment: @MaheerAli, you can test using the 'Run code snippet'

Comment: @MaheerAli, if you think your problem is solved, you can mark this solution as correct solution. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually your onclick function is binding on the this.cir object. So "this" object inside the clicking() function will refer to this.cir object. If you want to access name property inside clicking() function then you can add one more line as following code.

```
function unit(name,svgCircle)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.cir = svgCircle;
    this.cir.name = name;
    this.cir.onclick = clicking;
}
function clicking(){
    alert(this.name);
}
```